# Need Floating Point Precision Using Unsigned Int

Tags: c, floating-point, integer

I'm working with a microchip that doesn't have room for floating point precision, however. I need to account for fractional values during some equations. So far I've had good luck using the old *100 -> /100 method like so:

```
increment = (short int)(((value1 - value2)*100 / totalSteps));

// later in the code I loop through the number of totolSteps
// adding back the increment to arrive at the total I want at the precise time
// time I need it. 
newValue = oldValue + (increment / 100);
```

This works great for values from 0-255 divided by a totalSteps of up to 300. After 300, the fractional values to the right of the decimal place, become important, because they add up over time of course.

I'm curious if anyone has a better way to save decimal accuracy within an integer paradigm? I tried using *1000 /1000, but that didn't work at all.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about making the smallest increment you need to care about equal to `1`? Then the real value is just the `unsigned int` multiplied by a scale factor. Think of it as calculating in cents (0.01) instead of dollars/euros/whatever.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the algorithm you're trying to implement. Are you summing up a bunch a series of integers N1/1 + N2/2 + N3/3 + .. + N300/300? At any rate I'd suggest that you study fixed-point and rational arithmetic (or switch to a larger MCU.)

Comment: I'm creating a gradient from the first value to the second value over a given number of cycles. So the lets say 0 - 200 / *totalSteps* = the increment used to phase 0 to 200 (after checking its polarity +/- in a subroutine). Essentially the phasing has to complete exactly at the given cycle. It's working, but it's skipping at least 2 iterations when the *totalSteps* goes over 300.

Comment: you shouldn't try to implement fixed point precision with base 10, use base two instead. this has the advantage that the division can be done with a shift operation, and perhaps also that cummulated errors behave a bit nicer.

Comment: So I should store the entire value shifted however many places of precision to the left, then shift it back to the right at the last second and cast the final value? That makes complete sense.

Comment: Ah, so it's a linear interpolation. Then instead of pre-calculating a fractional step in limited precision I would suggest that evaluate the function at each iteration (e.g. source + (target - source) * index / steps). Take care to use sufficient integer precision along the way to avoid overflow though.

Comment: Good suggestion. However, our chip is a tiny little 8-bit motor, and chugs a bit too much with that equation live, so this is why I do the precalc. I'll try it again and see. Thank you for the help!

Comment: In that case the traditional method of increasing the precision while maintaining performance is through rational numbers. Look into Bresenham's algorithm.

Comment: I am really interested in you solution pls inform ! Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Fractions with integers is called **fixed point** math.

Try Googling "fixed point".

Fixed point tips and tricks are out of the scope of SO answer...

Example: 5 tap FIR filter

// C is the filter coefficients using 2.8 fixed precision.
// 2 MSB (of 10) is for integer part and 8 LSB (of 10) is the fraction part.
// Actual fraction precision here is 1/256.

```
int FIR_5(int* in,    // input samples
          int inPrec, // sample fraction precision
          int* c,     // filter coefficients
          int cPrec)  // coefficients fraction precision
{
    const int coefHalf = (cPrec > 0) ? 1 << (cPrec - 1) : 0; // value of 0.5 using cPrec
    int sum = 0; 
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
    {
        sum += in[i] * c[i];
    }

    // sum's precision is X.N. where N = inPrec + cPrec;
    // return to original precision (inPrec)
    sum = (sum + coefHalf) >> cPrec; // adding coefHalf for rounding
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    const int filterPrec = 8;
    int C[5] = { 8, 16, 208, 16, 8 }; // 1.0 == 256 in 2.8 fixed point. Filter value are 8/256, 16/256, 208/256, etc.
    int W[5] = { 10, 203, 40, 50, 72}; // A sampling window (example)
    int res = FIR_5(W, 0, C, filterPrec);
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:**

In the above example:

- the samples are integers (no fraction)
- the coefs have fractions of 8 bit.
- 8 bit fractions mean that each change of `1` is treated as 1/256. `1 << 8 == 256`.
- Useful notation is Y.Xu or Y.Xs. where Y is how many bits are allocated for the integer part and X for he fraction. u/s denote signed/unsigned.
- when multiplying 2 fixed point numbers, their precision (size of fraction bits) are added to each other.
- Example A is 0.8u, B is 0.2U. C=A*B. C is 0.10u
- when dividing, use a shift operation to lower the result precision. Amount of shifting is up to you. Before lowering precision it's better to add a `half` to lower the error.
- Example: A=129 in 0.8u which is a little over 0.5 (129/256). We want the integer part so we right shift it by 8. Before that we want to add a `half` which is 128 (1<<7). So A = (A + 128) >> 8 --> 1.
- Without adding a half you'll get a larger error in the final result.

Comment: Updated the answer with a real world example.

Comment: It's going to take a bit to completely understand you proposed solution, but I will figure it out! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this approach.

New paradigm: Do not accumulate using FP math or fixed point math.  Do your *accumulation* and other equations with integer math.  Anytime you need to get some scaled value, divide by your scale factor (100), but do the "add up" part with the raw, unscaled values.

Comment: @Mark Löwe  This is how I've handled stepper control in 8-bit PICs.

Comment: fixed point and integer math is the same thing both use integer operations.

Comment: @egur Agreed, [Fixed point math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic#Representation) is a scaled integer and can be nothing more than a scaled `int`.  There can be subtle variations on how to do operations like division and rounding in fixed point math (round to nearest) that could differ from C `int` division and rounding (truncate toward zero).  This small differences depend on how the fixed point math is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick attempt at a precise rational (Bresenham-esque) version of the interpolation if you truly cannot afford to directly interpolate at each step.

```
div_t frac_step = div(target - source, num_steps);
if(frac_step.rem < 0) {
    // Annoying special case to deal with rounding towards zero.
    // Alternatively check for the error term slipping to < -num_steps as well
    frac_step.rem = -frac_step.rem;
    --frac_step.quot;
}

unsigned int error = 0;

do {
    // Add the integer term plus an accumulated fraction
    error += frac_step.rem;
    if(error >= num_steps) {
        // Time to carry
        error -= num_steps;
        ++source;
    }
    source += frac_step.quot;
} while(--num_steps);
```

A major drawback compared to the fixed-point solution is that the fractional term gets rounded off between iterations if you are using the function to continually walk towards a moving target at differing step lengths.

Oh, and for the record your original code does not seem to be properly accumulating the fractions when stepping, e.g. a 1/100 increment will always be truncated to 0 in the addition no matter how many times the step is taken. Instead you really want to add the increment to a higher-precision fixed-point accumulator and then divide it by 100 (or preferably right shift to divide by a power-of-two) each iteration in order to compute the integer "position".

Do take care with the different integer types and ranges required in your calculations. A multiplication by 1000 will overflow a 16-bit integer unless one term is a long. Go through you calculations and keep track of input ranges and the headroom at each step, then select your integer types to match.

Comment: This is great advice. You are right on all fronts. I moved things out to a 1000 multiplier and got the overflow you spoke of. I'm going to give a couple of the examples (one being yours) a try on this page. Very much appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simulate floating point behaviour by saving
it using the IEEE 754 specification

So you save mantisse, exponent, and sign as unsigned int values.

For calculation you use then bitwise addition of mantisse and exponent and so on.
Multiplication and Division you can replace by bitwise addition operations.

I think it is a lot of programming staff to emulate that but it should work.

Comment: I rather doubt that a home-grown floating-point implementation would much smaller than one the compiler vendor provides and which the OP lacks room for. A simplified special-case format with byte-aligned fields and the like may help but fixed-point is likely to be far less error-prone.

Comment: Yeah your right. Was just a suggestion. I also think it's quite complicated. But it possible to apply a customized bitlengt for mantisse , exponent and so on, so that it maybe meets the hardware prerequisites.

Comment: Home-grown floating-point is actually an excellent learning experience and quite a fun project, so I'd suggest it for that reason. Unfortunately correctly implementing IEEE-754 is quite subtle.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of type is the problem: `short int` is likely to be 16 bits wide. That's why large multipliers don't work - you're limited to +/-32767. Use a 32 bit `long int`, assuming that your compiler supports it. What chip is it, by the way, and what compiler?

Comment: Yeah, my little chip has a 16bit int limit. :(